# Angular 5 material date picker

Tags: angular

I need a functionality on Angular 5 date picker which provides option pick date based on daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly view. The following link is available for Angular 1.X versions.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

I need a similar support for Angular 5. We have also explored the below option using jquery
`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/4mwk0d5L/1/ , but it would be better if the look and feel is like angular

Comment: pretty sure angular material date picker (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) has most of the functionality you describe, (check out Datepicker with filter validation). for selecting quarters I would write a component for that as it's more simple

Comment: Hi @Shaniqwa, Thanks for your response, I found that date validation is helpful. However, In case of monthly view, quarterly or yearly view i need to display only the month and not the entire calendar with disabled dates. similarly for quarter as in jfidlle link shared. I will have a combo box for the user to select which type of report and based on that i can display the calendar. Please can you help me with montly , quarterly and yearly selection such that the dates are not available for the user to select.

Comment: i am done with configuring for all the required reporting period. However i could not hide the date selection when the report for  month to be selected

Comment: Hi @Shaniqwa, Please can you help me on how to hide the date selection in date picker

Answer (score -1):

You can use "ng2-daterangepicker".

Please refer below link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker

In the .html file, you can have following code

```
<div class="input-date-range-picker mx-3" daterangepicker [options]="{ opens: 'left' }"
    (selected)="selectedDate($event, mainInput)">
    <a> <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    {{ mainInput.start | date:'M/dd/y' }} - {{ mainInput.end| date:'M/dd/y' }}
    </a>
</div>
```

(selected)="selectedDate($event, mainInput)" : will be the function call once you select the date.
mainInput : This is the default date selection parameter.

In .ts file add the following code.

```
import {DaterangePickerComponent, DaterangepickerConfig} from 'ng2-daterangepicker';

export class MyTestComponent implements OnInit {
    mainInput = {
        start: moment().subtract(1, 'month'),
        end: moment()
    };

    constructor(private daterangepickerOptions: DaterangepickerConfig) {
        this.daterangepickerOptions.settings = {
            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            },
            alwaysShowCalendars: false,
            ranges: {
                'Last Month': [
                    moment().subtract(1, 'month'),
                    moment()
                ],
                'Last 3 Months': [
                    moment().subtract(4, 'month'),
                    moment()
                ],
                'Last 6 Months': [
                    moment().subtract(6, 'month'),
                    moment()
                ],
                'Last 12 Months': [
                    moment().subtract(12, 'month'),
                    moment()
                ]
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Link references a Bootstrap-styled Date Range picker, OP asked for Material-styled

Answer (score -1):

I have used kekeh/mydatepicker, you can download it in the next url;

https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

In the .html file:

```
<div>
    <my-date-picker style="display:inline-block;" initialDate="null" 
    formControlName="date" locale="es" [options]="optionsDate"></my-date-picker>
</div>
```

.ts file:

```
import { IMyDpOptions, IMyDateModel, IMyDate, MyDatePicker } from 'mydatepicker';

// some stuff

export class.... {
    optionsDate: IMyDpOptions = {
        inline: false,
        disableUntil: { year: 0, month: 0, day: 0 },
        disableDays: [{ year: 0, month: 0, day: 0 }],
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        showWeekNumbers: false,
        selectorHeight: '232px',
        selectorWidth: '252px'
    };
}
```

Comment: Link references a Bootstrap-styled Date Range picker, OP asked for Material-styled

Comment: I have changed the link, the link now references a highly configurable Angular date picker

Comment: That is true, but it is still not Material themed, as requested by the OP.

Comment: The OP needs a "Similar" support, not specifically that of angular material